# matplotlib savefig cropping last row and column

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to plot the maze being traversed, when I do use plt.show() I get the entire maze whereas when I save the same image using savefig the last row and coloumn being plotted gets cropped/cut off.

This is the code used for plotting the maze. (I have attached the screenshots of the maze.)

```
def maze_plot_final(maze):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.cla()
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap()
    cmap.set_bad("white")
    ax.imshow(maze, cmap=cmap)
    plt.savefig('figs/dfs-new.png', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight',)
```

[The entire maze traversed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyLO4.png)

[This is the screenshot of the image generated by savefig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls2cg.png)

[This is the screenshot of the last part of maze shown by plt.show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elONu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the axis limits before saving?

```
plt.xlim(tuple_x)
plt.ylim(tuple_y)
```

where tuple_x:

```
(x0,xf) := interval of interest
```